# Why am I getting this Compile Error: Type Mismatch

Tags: excel, vba, userform, listobject, excel-tables

Hello everyone I am getting a compile Error: Type Does not match. in the code below. I was hoping you folks can help me out. Thank you!

```
Private Sub cmbBusId_AfterUpdate()

With Me

.txtStOdo = Application.WorksheetFunction.MaxIfs(Range("DataTable").ListObject.ListColumns("Ending Odometor"), (Range("DataTable").ListObject.ListColumns("Bus ID")), Me.cmbBusId)

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Remove the parentheses around the second argument?

Comment: I tried same error message I removed the Parentheses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### `ListColumns.DataBodyRange`

- [`MAXIFS function`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/maxifs-function-dfd611e6-da2c-488a-919b-9b6376b28883)(Microsoft)
- This code has to be written in the sheet module, where you refer to the worksheet with the `Me` keyword. The worksheet contains a text box and a combo box. The `DataTable` (named) range consists of at least one cell contained in the `ListObject` (Excel structured table).
- The error is occurring because you did not use just the '`DataBodyRange` part' of the list columns.
- Both examples use a `ListObject` variable (`tbl`) to make the code more readable.
- The first example uses line separators, while the second example uses variables to easily distinguish the `MaxIfs` parameters.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub cmbBusId_AfterUpdate1()

    With Me
        Dim tbl As ListObject: Set tbl = .Range("DataTable").ListObject
        .txtStodo = Application.WorksheetFunction.MaxIfs( _
            tbl.ListColumns("Ending Odometor").DataBodyRange, _
            tbl.ListColumns("Bus ID").DataBodyRange, _
            .cmbBusId)
    End With

End Sub

Private Sub cmbBusId_AfterUpdate2()

    With Me
        
        Dim tbl As ListObject: Set tbl = .Range("DataTable").ListObject
        Dim mrg As Range ' Max Range
        Set mrg = tbl.ListColumns("Ending Odometor").DataBodyRange
        Dim crg1 As Range ' Criteria Range 1
        Set crg1 = tbl.ListColumns("Bus ID").DataBodyRange
        Dim Criteria1 As Double ' Criteria 1
        Criteria1 = .cmbBusId
        
        .txtStodo = Application.WorksheetFunction.MaxIfs(mrg, crg1, Criteria1)
    
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: First of all, thank you so much for your detailed response it's more than I could hope for. When I input the code it's giving me an error on .Range is now giving me an error Method or Data member not found. I am relatively new using VBA any help will be great thank you!

Comment: Not sure, but I would guess that `Me` does not refer to a worksheet, so qualify the range appropriately (e.g. `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("DataTable").ListObject`) or just remove the dot (`.`)(not recommended).